# Meta Ads Shows 0 impressions in Admob Mediation

Tags: mobile-ad-mediation

Admob Dashboard showing various of ads requests but ultimately zero impressions in Meta.
Basically I have four mediation networks Meta,AppLovin,Unity,Mintegral. Instead meta every network is showing requests and impressions.

I have tried different meta adapter versions but in vain.

Comment: Hello there, exactly the same is happening to me. Have you figured out the reason already?

Comment: Yeah I found the Solution by implementing different strategies and got the culprit. Just you need to add that version of SDK which is recommended by the google adapter. I have used GMA SDK 8.1.0 to solve this issue !

Comment: But this version of GMA is super old, no? Or you mean the Facebook Mediation SDK?

Comment: no i m talking about meta adapter ! nor about sdk

Comment: Hey @FrederikoRibeiro did you solved your problem? if not then try Google Mobile Admob SDK 8.5.1  and adapter version( 3.11.0) to solve this issue ,

Download From link:

Comment: Meta Adapter from there:https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/mediation/meta#meta-audience-network-unity-mediation-plugin-changelog

Comment: Google Mobile Admob SDK 8.5.1
from there: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases

Comment: Hello, thank you! The problem was solved but I had to install the Facebook SDK to my app.